# How to throw custom errors on some routes in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, custom-errors

I get custom error if I do something like

```
https://localhost:xxxx/TryStuff
```

but if I do something like

```
https://localhost:xxxx/AbcController/Details/1234/TryStuff
```

it doesn't throw a custom error. It throws something like

[image]

Route file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Error",
        action = "NotFound",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Comment: Show how you configured your routes

Comment: That should be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50762790/edit) into the question not comments.

Comment: But my guess is everything is treated as id even /tryStuff on the back after 1234

Comment: No you need a catch all parameter `routes.MapRoute( name: "Error", url: "{*url}", defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a catch all route

```
//Catch-All InValid (NotFound) Routes
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotFound",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
);
```

Add this route after all other routes.

Any routes that are not caught before will match this one and route to the appropriate controller.